# Cloned CentOS not booting up

Tags: linux, hard-drive, centos, clonezilla

I recently cloned a CentOS6 environment from 1TB HDD and intended to restore its image to a 4 TB space. I used Clonezilla for this.

The clone went successful, but after that when I tried to restore the cloned-image   to the new hard disk space, the system is not booting up. The restoration process went successful but still the system says no booting point found.

I check online, but people who had faced that same issue was mostly dealing with Windows system, that got recovered from Windows CD. For me, I am using CentOS6. I don't have that option. What strategy should I adopt so that I can boot up the backed up enviornment into the new system?

Comment: What version of centos?  Is the bios declaring the boot failure or do you get to grub? Did you do a full disk clone or a partition clone?  For starters this link might help (its for grub2 , introduced in centos 7). I don't know without more info: https://www.linux.com/learn/how-rescue-non-booting-grub-2-linux

Comment: Boot from a Live DVD-ROM or USB flash drive and do a closer examination of the 4 TB space. Do fdisk -l, see if things were configuration properly. Also, check the BIOS to make sure you are booting from the desired device.

Comment: Also check the fstab file, as if it was configured for a specific UID for a drive, it is likely different on the new one.